# Small styling discrepancies using React with Material-UI in SharePoint Online (non-SPFx)

Tags: sharepoint-online, react

When I build and publish my React application which uses Material-UI, to SharePoint Online I see a couple of small styling issues. It appears SPO's styling is being inherited by my Material-UI components in some places and I'm wondering if there's a way to better isolate them at the application level.

For example, my card action buttons function but are stretched horizontally.
[image: card action button]

Also, my TextField components still have the nice floating label effect, but get a border around them.
[image: textfield elements]

Note that this application is not a SPFx project. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

It's been awhile since I worked in the situation that you are describing (MaterialUI and React within Sharepoint Online) but if I remember correctly, I used MaterialUI's higher order component **withStyles** to help get the styling into the component.

Check it out: https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/#higher-order-component-api

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a look!